# Is the Azure disk space for App Service just for files related to running the App, or can file uploads from users be stored there too?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

just wondering if the disk space the comes with App Service packages is only for files related to running the web application, or if it can be used for storing user uploads like images and files?

Or do you have to get extra storage if want to store user uploaded content like images, files, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose to store whatever you want within your Web App's allocated disk space. It's *durable* storage, meaning it is replicated and won't go away unless you delete the files or completely decommission your Web App (e.g. delete the Web App).

You will need to manage your disk space carefully, since it is capped, based on the App Service tier you choose.

Also: Storage in a Web App is shared across instances of the Web App. If you use a local database such as Sqlite, for example, all instances of your web app would have the same access to that sqlite file.

Note: There are plenty of examples where apps are storing local databases in Web App storage (such as the ghost blog and others).

You can, of course, utilize Azure Storage as well (which scales far beyond Web Apps, and is accessible independent of your Web App, offering additional features you can read up on). The only thing you cannot do with Azure Storage is mount an Azure Files storage area to your Web App (you would need to use an SDK / REST API calls to work with files in an Azure Files space).

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use Blob storage and add upload and download options in the website. You can then download using an URL and add authentication using SAS tokens.

Comment: Thanks! Would the best fit for this application be Azure Files Storage? Once  these are uploaded, they shouldn't be accessible to anyone except us internally. Users upload files for us to review, so they would just upload and we would download it.

Comment: @sockpuppet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks    You could look at blob storage which is a lot cheaper to use than azure file storage

Comment: This answer is not accurate. Storage in Web Apps is *durable* (replicated, won't go away) unless you delete the files yourself, or physically delete the Web App. There is no concept of storage recycling in Web Apps, only the app pool gets recycled, depending on options set and tier chosen.

Comment: @Chao226 - not sure what you mean by "a lot cheaper" - Azure Files has a similar type of pricing model as Blob storage. But it provides a different interface (SMB), which might be required by legacy apps.

Comment: @sockpuppet - there are inaccuracies in this answer. And Azure Files cannot be direct-mounted to a Web App as a drive, as you can do with a VM - you'd have to use API calls (or language-specific SDK) to work with it. Please see my answer, which also points this out specifically.

Comment: @DavidMakogon looking at the azure price calculator.  based on 1tb block blob storage hot = £15.87 a month file storage = £45.79 a month.  there is also a difference in costing for operations for these.